# Add new items to my shopping cart in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a simple online food ordering system. The issue I'm facing is that when I click on the add button, the corresponding item is added to the cart. But when I click the add button of another item, the existing item in the cart gets updated instead appended as the next item.

Below is an important part of the code.

**Orders.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import Menu from '../components/Menu'
import data from '../data/data.json'
import MyCart from '../components/MyCart'

class Orders extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        list: data,
        id:'',
        newList:[],
        price:'',
        name:'',
        total:0,
        quantity:0,
        clickable: false
    };
}
childHandler = (ChildPrice,ChildName,ChildQuantity) => {

    this.setState(
        {price: ChildPrice,
        name: ChildName,
        quantity : ChildQuantity+1,
        clickable: true }
    )};
render(){
    return(
    <div>
         <div id='items'>
                    <center><h2>Order Now</h2></center>
                    <br/>

                    {this.state.newList.map (
                        x => x.menu.map(item => <Menu
                                                    desc={item.desc} 
                                                    price={item.price} 
                                                    name={item.name}
                                                    action={this.childHandler} />)
                    )       

                    }

                </div>
        <div id= "right-in">
                        <h4>My Cart</h4>

                        { this.state.clickable && 
                            <div>
                                <MyCart 
                                    name={this.state.name}
                                    price={this.state.price}
                                    quantity={this.state.quantity} 
                                    increment={this.incrementQuantity} 
                                    decrement={this.decrementQuantity}>
                                </MyCart>
                            </div>
                        }

                        <div id="total">
                            <p id="total"> Total amount: 
                                <span className="spn">{'\u20B9'}  {this.state.total}</span>
                            </p>
                            <input id="pay" type="button" value="Calculate"
                            onClick = {() => this.total(this.state.price,this.state.quantity)} />
                            <br/>
                            <input id="pay" type="button" value="Pay Now"/>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
</div>
```

**Menu.js**

```
import React from 'react'
class Menu extends React.Component{

constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        price: '',
        quantity:0
    }
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h3 className='fname'>{this.props.name}</h3>
                <div className='desc'>
                    <p>{this.props.desc}</p>
                    <button className="btn" value={this.props.price} onClick={()=>this.props.action(this.props.price,this.props.name,this.state.quantity)}>Add</button>
                </div>
                <br/>   
                <p className='amount'>{'\u20B9'}  {this.props.price} </p>

        </div>

    )
}
}

export default Menu;
```

**MyCart.js**

```
import React from 'react'
class MyCart extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <p id="pitem"> {this.props.name} <br/><br/>
                    <input className="ip" type="button" value="-" onClick={()=>this.props.decrement(this.props.quantity)}/>
                    <input className="ip" id="tx-w" type="text" value={this.props.quantity}/>
                    <input className="ip" type="button" value="+" onClick={()=>this.props.increment(this.props.quantity)}/>
            </p>  
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default MyCart
```

Here is the screenshot of Orders Page

[image: Here is the screenshot of Orders Page]

Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The state is only a temporary option, you can't add to state, you can only update it.
in my opinion, you should use a database to hold those items temporarily.
or use sessions.

Comment: Where's the code responsible for adding items to the `cart`?

Comment: @AhmadAli Can we create an empty list in the state, appends new items to that list once the button is clicked and show the entire content of the list in the cart section?

Comment: @goto1 I have updated my question with MyCart.js code

Comment: Your `MyCart.js` is just some `JSX` code. Where's the piece of code that stores items you've added to the `Cart`? Something long the lines of `this.setState({ cart: [existingItems, newItem] })`

Comment: @goto1 You can see it in `right-in` div. I have a variable called `clickable` in my state which is set to false initially. When I click on the Add button (in Menu.js), I set the clickable as true, and the contents of the MyCart will be displayed. Hope I got it correctly!

Comment: Your cannot have duplicate id's `id="tx-w"` and `id="pitem"`in HTML ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score -1):

change state name property type as array instead of string:

```
this.state = {
        list: data,
        id:'',
        newList:[],
        price:'',
        name:[],    //name should be an array not a string
        total:0,
        quantity:0,
        clickable: false
    };

childHandler = (ChildPrice,ChildName,ChildQuantity) => {
    const names = this.state.name; 
    names.push(childName);
    this.setState(
        {price: ChildPrice,
        name: names,
        quantity : ChildQuantity+1,
        clickable: true }
    )};
```

In your cart page props.name should be an array instead of string.

```
    import React from 'react'
    class MyCart extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
               {this.props.name.map((name,number) => (
                    <p key={number} id="pitem"> 
                        {name} <br/><br/>
                     </p>
                    )}
               <p>
                        <input className="ip" type="button" value="-" onClick={()=>this.props.decrement(this.props.quantity)}/>
                        <input className="ip" id="tx-w" type="text" value={this.props.quantity}/>
                        <input className="ip" type="button" value="+" onClick={()=>this.props.increment(this.props.quantity)}/>
                </p> 
            </div>
        )
    }
    }

    export default MyCart
```